# Um usuário está confundindo a minha pergunta sem parar

Tags: debate

Acabei de fazer uma pergunta ([O que são tabelas fracas?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/177660)) sobre Lua, de como deixar as referências dos campos de uma tabela serem fracas, que na minha opinião está clara e tem um exemplo mostrando uma tabela recebendo campos com chaves referenciadoras de tabelas. O penúltimo trecho

> Existe alguma maneira de fazer os campos de `tables` serem coletados pelo lixo nesse caso?

já indica o que tem que ocorrer no código de exemplo, mas esse [usuário](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/101) está comentando que o código está deixando a pergunta confusa e difícil de entender.

[image]

Ele respondeu e continua inventando falhas na minha pergunta. O que fazer? Já <s>denunciei</s> sinalizei ele, mas nada foi feito até agora.

Comment: Você está denunciando uma pessoa que está tentando lhe apontar problemas para facilitar as pessoas entenderem melhor a sua pergunta? Cara isso é um péssimo uso da ferramenta sinalizar, se alguem estivesse lhe xingando ou ofendendo ae seria um bom uso, mas porque a pessoa está lhe apontando problemas na pergunta com a intenção de lhe ajudar é um baita engano seu.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento Hmm, só que a pessoa só fala da mesma coisa, "que a pergunta não está específica". Eu tentei ser o mais minimal possível e está clara, basta ler a pergunta

Comment: Não importa se a pergunta esta clara para vc, o que importa é se ela esta clara para os demais usuários, os que iram responder e para quem tiver a mesma dúvida que vc. O bigown estava tentando lhe ajudar, mas parece que vc não se importo com isso e se ofendeu com alguma coisa. Em relação a pergunta, ela precisa de um contexto, assim seria melhor.

Comment: @gato Sim, ela tem um contexto de exemplo.

Comment: Eu não estou falando da pergunta e da discussão, estou falando do uso indevido da ferramenta sinalizar. De qualquer forma entenda, para você algo pode ser uma pergunta clara, pois está na sua cabeça e para outras pessoas pode ser que o texto esteja dificil, agora o fato é mesmo que ele esteja enganado ele não fez por mal, é apenas uma critica construtiva e nada mais e sinalizar assim sem necessidade porque vc não sabe levar uma critica é um uso totalmente indevido. Espero que entenda.

Answer (score 19):

A pergunta é tua, podes aceitar a resposta que achares melhor, tua ou não. A intenção do bigown foi de clarificar questionando a pergunta. Ainda que pareça exaustivo ele explicou as suas razões para questionar.

Acho injustificado dizer que ele *"está deixando a pergunta confusa e difícil de entender"*, pois a pergunta deve sozinha ser suficiente para ser percebida, e ao menos para ele, não foi (e repare que é o utilizador com mais pontuação em todo o site).

Todos nós temos direito de pedir explicações sobre perguntas e respostas, quem faz a pergunta escolhe que resposta aceitar.

Contudo, o teu comportamento a seguir a postar novas respostas com palavrões matou a discussão e deixou essa página pouco séria.

És bem-vindo à comunidade, mas tens de melhorar o código de conduta e não tomar perguntas como as que recebeste como críticas profundas à tua pessoa.

Ficou uma reposta meio *meta*física talvez, mas espero que vá ao encontro do que acho da tua pergunta aqui e da [tua atuação lá](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/177707/129).