# Alteração na pontuação em perguntas: votos positivos passarão a valer 10 pontos ao invés de 5

Tags: novo-recurso

Hoje, dia 13 de Novembro de 2019, saiu este aviso:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Que leva a página  [We’re Rewarding the Question Askers](https://stackoverflow.blog/2019/11/13/were-rewarding-the-question-askers/) .

Segue uma versão traduzida do texto a quem interessar:

---

No meu [primeiro post](https://stackoverflow.blog/2019/07/18/building-community-inclusivity-stack-overflow/) escrevi sobre o que uma experiência pessoal me ensinou sobre a comunidade Stack Overflow. Eu disse que iríamos dar um passo atrás e reavaliar como fornecemos *feedback*, como podemos melhorar a qualidade do conteúdo e como podemos reduzir o atrito entre as pessoas. Eu disse que nosso objetivo é fazer com que o processo de perguntas seja indolor e benéfico para novas pessoas e veteranos do Stack Overflow.

Durante esse período de reavaliação, notamos algo em nosso sistema de recompensa de reputação. Damos a qualquer um que recebe um voto positivo em uma resposta dez pontos de reputação adicionais, mas apenas cinco pontos de reputação a pessoas que recebem um voto positivo em uma pergunta.

Aqui está a história: Quando o Stack Overflow foi lançado em 2007, atribuímos pontos iguais aos upvotes de respostas e perguntas. Três anos depois, foi tomada uma decisão para desvalorizar a reputação de voto positivo em questões. A idéia era que essa mudança encorajaria as pessoas a se concentrarem em fornecer respostas de boa qualidade, em vez de fazer perguntas.

Podemos analisar essa decisão com o benefício da retrospectiva. Essa decisão pode ter sido a decisão certa com as informações que tínhamos na época, mas vimos os efeitos que isso teve em nossa comunidade. Recompensamos as pessoas que dão respostas a uma taxa maior do que as que fazem perguntas.

Há muito tempo, membro da comunidade Stack Overflow, sei, como muitos de vocês, que postar uma boa pergunta é difícil! Exige reflexão e atenção à melhor maneira de transmitir o problema que você está tendo. Você precisa dar um passo atrás e fingir que está descrevendo seu problema para um total estranho que não tem contexto em torno de sua situação. Eles não estão vendo seus logs de compilação e não sabem qual é o recurso que você está criando, quais bibliotecas você está usando ou qual versão da estrutura está em sua máquina.

Você também precisa estar ciente do fato de que existem muitas informações estranhas. Você precisa saber quais partes da mensagem de erro incluir e quais são exclusivas da sua máquina. Você precisa incluir as etapas que você executou até agora e o resultado dos seus testes. Em resumo, você precisa ser um especialista em perguntas para garantir que obterá a melhor resposta. Isso requer habilidade e experiência, é valioso e é algo que queremos comemorar.

A partir de hoje, estamos executando de volta. Estamos mudando a reputação conquistada com a obtenção de uma pergunta positiva para dez pontos, tornando-a igual à reputação conquistada com uma resposta positiva.

Estamos recalculando a reputação de todos os indivíduos Stack Overflow e Stack Exchange com base nessa alteração. Todas as perguntas votadas anteriormente ganharão um valor de dez pontos de reputação retroativamente.

No Stack Overflow, esperamos que cerca de 2,4 milhões de pessoas ganhem mais reputação. Essa mudança é mais do que reputação; queremos que ele envie uma mensagem clara - comemoramos as perguntas. HOORAY PARA OS PERGUNTAS!

Para aqueles que estão recebendo novos privilégios: pedimos que assuma a responsabilidade com reverência. Você é o especialista em perguntas. Vocês são as pessoas que conseguem identificar uma pergunta que está tendo problemas e sabem o quão difícil pode ser para o outro lado desse teclado. Agradecemos antecipadamente por treinar gentilmente os solicitantes de perguntas através de suas experiências.

Acreditamos que tanto os que fazem perguntas quanto os que respondem são uma parte vital do nosso ecossistema. Agradecemos o quanto eles fizeram para tornar essa a maior loja de perguntas e respostas técnicas da história e queremos agradecer a eles por todas as contribuições que voltaram ao início do site.

Estamos fazendo mais.

Implementamos uma experiência aprimorada para fazer perguntas no Stack Overflow (sites de Stack Exchange, vocês obterão isso no primeiro trimestre). Meg Risdal [visualizou as melhorias](https://stackoverflow.blog/2019/08/20/upcoming-on-stack-overflow/) em agosto e Lisa Park deu uma [olhada nos bastidores](https://stackoverflow.blog/2019/09/26/research-update-improving-the-question-asking-experience/) da pesquisa que levou ao desenvolvimento das melhorias em setembro. Não poderíamos estar mais empolgados em divulgar isso para todos!

Ontem, Julia Silge publicou uma [recapitulação dos resultados](https://www.google.com/url?q=https://stackoverflow.blog/2019/11/12/research-update-a-b-testing-the-new-question-form) de nosso teste A/B na nova experiência. Vimos um aumento significativo no número de pessoas que iniciaram e postaram uma pergunta. Também analisamos a qualidade das perguntas porque queríamos ter certeza de que estávamos ajudando todas as pessoas a escrever perguntas que provavelmente seriam respondidas. Não vimos nenhuma diminuição na qualidade da pergunta.

Resumo: as alterações que fizemos estão aumentando o número de perguntas publicadas no Stack Overflow, sem diminuir a qualidade. Mais perguntas de alta qualidade; esta é a comunidade onde todos podem prosperar.

Eu já disse isso antes e direi novamente - eu e a equipe da comunidade estamos realmente empolgados em melhorar a experiência que todos os níveis de codificadores têm no Stack Overflow, desde novos usuários que estão aprendendo front-end pela primeira vez a nossos moderadores respeitados que codificam há mais de 20 anos. Essas mudanças - aumentando os pontos de reputação para upvotes de perguntas e a experiência aprimorada de perguntas -, juntamente com alguns novos mecanismos de feedback que anunciaremos na próxima semana, são um começo empolgante para trabalhar lado a lado com a comunidade para criar um Stack Overflow melhor.

Comment: Trágico! Definitivamente o SO não é mais o que eu acho que devia ser e acho que as coisas vão piorar, preciso repensar algumas coisas.

Comment: Relacionado: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/338113/401803

Comment: Para quem quiser estimar quanto de reputação ganhará no processo: https://data.stackexchange.com/pt/query/1148164/estimated-rep-bump-from-question-upvote-change

Comment: Quem mais fez perguntas: https://data.stackexchange.com/pt/query/1027796/top-askers-of-so

Comment: @hkotsubo essa query é bem ingênua, não considera o cap. Eu vou ganhar muito pouco apesar disso dar mais de 20k, já o pnet vai ganhar horrores pq ñ tem cap, o Wallace deve ganhar bem mas não 35K.

Comment: Eu também acho que vai piorar. Agora vai passar a compensar tem uma pergunta em -2 (1 upvote e 3 downvotes) pois ainda ganha 2 de reputação, mesmo sendo uma pergunta claramente fraca. Conclusão: menos preocupação em fazer uma pergunta com pés e cabeça, desde que de para capturar pelo menos 1 upvote.

Comment: @Maniero Mas não fui eu quem fez a query :-) Aliás, essa era minha dúvida, se vão levar em conta o cap no recálculo, ou se vão só adicionar 5 pontos pra cada voto na pergunta (já que o recálculo retroativo deve ser um job bem custoso...)

Comment: @hkotsubo sim, só estou falando pra ninguém achar que ela dá um resultado muito certo, se bem que o único que terá um resultado muito diferente serei eu :D O cap valerá com certeza. Eu estava capado boa parte dos dias, então vou aumentar bem pouco. Ou seja, serei punido por fazer o jogo direito :(

Comment: Entendedores entenderão: https://i.stack.imgur.com/VgoDM.jpg

Comment: Ficou mais importante agora pensar 10x antes de votar positivo em pergunta e não deixar de negativar quando precisa, ficou gostoso fazer pegunta ruim.

Comment: Mais uma vez a empresa diz que "escultou" (em teoria) as comunidade e faz o contrário do necessário?! Foi isso mesmo?

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento eles falaram que escutaram? Porque há discussões no metão dizendo o contrário. O que eu vejo é mais uma vez a esquizofrenia de dizer que vão melhorar a quantidade quando no máximo vai melhorar a quantidade.

Comment: Detalhe que quem mais perguntou foi o nulo (top-askers-of-so)

Comment: Achava que quando a pessoa desse um downvote em uma pergunta ou resposta, ela deveria perder pelo menos 1 ou 2 pontos de reputação. Para assim ela não dar downvote de sacanagem nos outros. E também para ela pensar 2 vezes pra ver se realmente vale a pena dar um downvote naquela pergunta ou resposta. Em relação ao critério de ganho e perda de pontos, eu acho justo.

Comment: @Maniero No metão já vi vários comentários dizendo que não consultaram a comunidade nessa alteração. E tem muita gente lá criticando que só trocam coisas inúteis, e que o que realmente interessa fica para trás. A discussão está bem acesa.

Comment: @Isac sim, tá complicado, é impressionante como eles resolveram que vão fazer tudo o que a comunidade não quer, porque agora só interessa angariar um monte de gente (eu prometi que vou pegar leve e não vou qualificar :D ) e não importa mais as pessoas que deram o sangue todo esse tempo, não precisa mais delas pra plataforma andar sozinha, não precisa mais de qualidade, só discurso importa, agora descamba de vez.

Comment: @Maniero tirando alguns detalhes, não é nada que não tivéssemos comentado que ia dar m* desde 2014... :)

Comment: Eu posso estar bem equivocado, mas no momento em que discussão de gênero se tornou mais importante que a discussão sobre código e leniência suplanta a competência, surge a imunidade para se perguntar de tudo um pouco fora do escopo. Me dá a entender que vão aumentar a penetração social do StackOverflow e o transformarão numa rede social  ̶p̶a̶r̶a̶ ̶n̶o̶o̶b̶s̶ objetivando ser uma vitrine para vender licenças do Teams.

Comment: +1 agora a valer 10 para a tradução -10 para a pior ideia da SE.

Comment: @AugustoVasques sua observação parece coerente, só que isso começou há algum tempo, um pouco antes do SOpt nascer (e que foi abandonado), houve a saída de um dos fundadores da empresa alegando que queria ficar mais tempo com a família (ele trabalhava em casa em EL Cerrito) e 2 meses depois ele anunciou que estava criando outra empresa com um ex-funcionário da SE, e já era um projeto que estava em gestação dentro dos famosos 6 a 8 semanas. Ele não saiu porque queria esse novo projeto, mas porque discordava do novo rumo que queriam dar para a SE, foi logo em seguida que tudo mudou pra pior.

Comment: Incluindo a troca de funcionários chave que gostavam dessas coisas que nada tem a ver com os valores da maioria dos usuários que fazem a rede ser um sucesso. Ali a qualidade foi trocada pela quantidade. È sintomático que esse fundador teve a grande sacada que pergunta não podia valer o mesmo que resposta e agora voltam atrás. Quase tudo o que esse fundador disse no blog da SE e fazia sentido, tinha uma visão clara do que era importante para a rede, desde sua saída esse conteúdo foi "esquecido" e sempre que discutimos algo e falávamos que estava em acordo com aquela visão, eles minimizam...

Comment: ... aquele conteúdo e sem dizer que o fundador não tinha mais valor mostravam que estavam adotando um outro caminho. O que é mais importante é que eles resolvem de vez não ouvir mais a comunidade. É hora de repensar o que estamos fazendo aqui. Tomo uma decisão até o fim do ano. Não ajuda o fato da comunidade não estar muito ativa mais e dá espaço para quem o pior é melhor. A ideia de comunidade gerir algo não deu certo, mas acho que isso foi um pouco sabotado também.

Comment: Algumas discussões no metão: [Should the weight of question upvotes be increased network-wide?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/337843), [What “effects” led to “We’re Rewarding the Question Askers”?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/338144) e [New Reputation Calculation - was the community asked?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/338113)

Comment: Vi algo parecido acontecer no Quora, mas o que ocorreu foi a recompensação em dinheiro (alguns centavos) por perguntas com muita visualização. O que ocorreu foi uma chuva de perguntas com nível muito baixo, o que deixou o site mais desinteressante e fez muita gente sair...

Comment: E eu pensando sobre fazer um post sobre a responsabilidade dos usuários a respeito da nova reputação, mas pelo visto já não é necessário. Belo post!

Comment: @ThiaguinhoEmbasamento Em 2008 upvote em pergunta dava 10 pontos, em 2010 mudou pra 5 (a [justificativa na época](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/03/19/important-reputation-rule-changes) foi encorajar mais respostas que perguntas). Agora voltou pra 10, a justificativa é que a decisão de 2010 não surtiu efeito e tb querem incentivar mais perguntas. Ou seja, os motivos não tem nada a ver com "ser mais justo". E isso pode até incentivar mais perguntas, mas não vi nenhuma ação no sentido de melhorar a qualidade das mesmas, pra mim a empresa deixa claro que prefere mais quantidade que qualidade.

Comment: @ThiaguinhoEmbasamento E downvote em resposta custa 1 ponto pra quem vota ([hoje já é assim](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation)). Downvotes em **perguntas** não custam nada pra quem vota, e o motivo é explicado [aqui](https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/06/13/optimizing-for-pearls-not-sand). De qualquer forma, o custo de votar negativo em resposta não impede os votos "pra sacanear" (experiência própria, eu e muitos outros já sofremos com isso alguma vez).

Comment: Eu acho justo ter os downvotes nas perguntas, porém eu não vejo nada que impeça uma pessoa de sair dando downvotes nas perguntas digamos que de forma 'aleatória' (Para não dizer outra coisa) ou por motivos diferentes do motivo de 'qualidade ruim da pergunta'.

Comment: @ThiaguinhoEmbasamento mas ai o problema não é do sistema. O problema é a mentalidade das pessoas. Porque o sistema que estava antes funcionava bem. Poderia ser melhorado, claro, mas agora está a ser destruído. Estão a transformar isto em helpdesk, mas o que eles querem é números, a qualidade já foi um requisito, agora é cada vez menos.

Comment: @ThiaguinhoEmbasamento raramente vi downvotes aleatórios, só quando ocorria de 2 usuarios discutirem e saiam um atacando o outro, coisa que vi pouquissimas vezes, os demais (e grande maioria) foram downvotes de pessoas que tem conhecimento técnico para apontar que X postagem tem sim problema e preferem se omitir do comentário porque nem sempre o AP ou AR aceitam (quando comentado) que a postagem X tenha de fato um problema, geralmente por falta de entendimento técnico no assunto ou até mesmo confusão.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento , isso não teria como garantir. Pois nunca saberemos que só quem dará um downvote é um dos membros 'Experts' no assunto. Qualquer pessoa pode dar um downvote. Acho que não teria coerência uma pergunta ter 20 aprovações (por exemplo) e 2 downvotes. Então porque a pergunta não teria sido marcada ou algo do tipo ? Na minha humilde opinião essa questão, do downvote liberado, banaliza muito o voto negativo.

Comment: @ThiaguinhoEmbasamento então tem provas de quem perguntas com mais de um downvote foram parametrizados por usuários do caos mal intencionados dispostos a causar problemas de proposito gastando seu tempo apenas com isto e que eles não visam os problemas técnicos das postagens? Desculpe, mas isso me parece improvavel, já que você citou que é aleatório, o que eu desacredito, todas postagens que vi com downvote quase sempre notei problemas.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento , não é questão de 'usuários do caos', meu caro. É só questão muitas vezes de uma falta do que fazer ou talvez o cara sinta uma satisfação inexplicável em fazer isso. Não estou dizendo que é em todos os casos e nem na maioria. Estou falando que isso pode acontecer e talvez seria bom criarem uma medida preventiva quanto a isso.

Comment: ... Temos que ter critérios e bom senso para peguntas(sim), respostas, comportamento e para up e downvotes também.

Comment: @ThiaguinhoEmbasamento Mesmo que tenha usuários que dão votos negativos "aleatórios" por "falta do que fazer", esses são minoria e **isso é um problema menor, se comparado com outros problemas mais frequentes**, como por exemplo a enorme quantidade de perguntas ruins e gente que não quer aprender como usar o site (para os quais ações como [essa](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/314304/401803) seriam muito efetivas, mas a empresa ignora, pois cada vez mais estão deixando claro que o que importa pra eles é quantidade, e não qualidade...)

Comment: @ThiaguinhoEmbasamento: **"Eu acho justo ter os downvotes nas perguntas, porém eu não vejo nada que impeça uma pessoa de sair dando downvotes nas perguntas digamos que de forma 'aleatória'"**. O próprio sistema se encarrega de detectar e reverter serial downvoter e upvoters, o sistema também detecta votos em corrente e outros tipos de manipulação. Eu já sofri com ataque orquestrado e tive os down votes revertidos mesmo sem ter pedido restituição.

Comment: Mas acho que para o sistema reverter deve ser algo gritante. Não sei o critério, mas não deve ser por apenas alguns votos. O downvote não é o problema, o problema é com que propósito ele é dado pela pessoa. Mas realmente acho que isso é difícil de se avaliar. Por isso minha sugestão do downvote em perguntas valer alguns poucos pontos de reputação.

Comment: Entendi, um premio para o desleixo de uma pergunta ruim ou mal feita e punição para critica e orientação.

Comment: @ThiaguinhoEmbasamento em geral só tem votos negativos aleatórios quando a pessoa está querendo se vingar de alguém, os moderadores percebem isso com clareza por ter acesso a mais informações, em geral as pessoas que fazem isso são as que se revoltam com negativos, incoerente, né? Eu acho que o voto deveria ser mais restito mesmo, só para as pessoas que já mostraram que entendem do assunto e que não vão ficar negativando uma pessoa só porque não gosta dela ou porque ele fechou uma pergunta que ela tinha interesse.

Comment: @ThiaguinhoEmbasamento  Você acha que deveríamos punir mais intensamente quanto fica claro que uma pessoa está votando na pessoa e não no conteúdo? Nós temos agora várias pessoas que o sistema detectou irregularidade mas não de forma pesada por isso ele deixou para os moderadores decidirem, queremos a opinião de algumas pessoas para ajudar decidir, e a sua é importante para vermos o que fazer em alguns casos recentes. Não é só downs, tem ups também, dados entre amigos ou por conta marionete.

Comment: @Maniero , Qualquer atitude que parta para um contexto que fuja do proposto pelo Stackoverflow, deve sim ser punido. Só que quanto a isso, é muito difícil o sistema (justamente por ser um sistema) avaliar quando uma pessoa realmente deu downvote ou upvote com boa intenção ou não. A pessoa pode achar que a pergunta ou resposta foi útil pra ela, em um contexto particular dela e dar upvote. Agora, na questão do downvote não podemos avaliar em um contexto particular, pois a resposta pode não ter sido útil pra uma pessoa, mas pode ser útil para diversas outras.

Comment: @Maniero. Tem excelentes respostas aqui no Stack. Porém, além do conteúdo, tem algumas que o egocentrismo e prepotência impera mais que o próprio conteúdo. Então podem ter pessoas que avaliam isso também. Não sei se é o certo avaliar levando isso em consideração. Ai vai mais um ponto pra minha sugestão de deixarem de banalizar o downvote e cobrarem pontos de reputação para os que votam de forma negativa.

Comment: @ThiaguinhoEmbasamento por isso que estou pedindo sua opinião, o sistema nos dá informações de que algo parece errado, nós precisamos tomar a atitude final. Agora mesmo tem um caso de um grupo de 3 contas que votam entre si, ainda não decidimos se são amigos ou 3 contas da mesma pessoa, e pelo menos uma delas está negativando outra de forma bastante estranha e não parece ter critério conforme sua reclamação. Isso é uma avaliação dos moderadores, não do sistema. Então acha que devemos fazer algo em um caso assim?

Comment: @Maniero. Por exemplo,um dia aconteceu comigo de várias perguntas, respostas e comentários meus receberem negativações. Até em posts antigos que já nem apareciam mais no radar do Stack. Os votam foram completamente aleatórios e constantes. Não sei o que aconteceu. Eu fui na área da reclamação, mas o que consegui receber do Stack foi uma resposta totalmente genérica. Por isso minha sugestão. Serve pra pelo menos a pessoa pensar duas vezes antes de fazer tal ato. Claro que isso não funcionaria para uma pessoa que tenha uma reputação elevadíssima, porém acho que iria influenciar a massa inferior.

Comment: Lembrando que o negativo não deve ser dado porque não foi útil mas porque ela está errada, e não pode ser dado em perseguição a uma pessoa provavelmente por se vingar que essa pessoa fechou pergunta dela. Quando a pessoa negativa algo porque não gostou da pessoa está errado. É impressão minha ou você está dizendo que vota porque não gosta do jeito que a pessoa escreve ou se comporta, e aí negativa por isso? Ou você é contra isso? Não ficou bem claro.

Comment: Falei nada, minha intenção aqui é de apenas sugerir a cobrança de reputação dos downvotes.

Comment: O sistema não indicou nada errado nas votações negativas em você inclusive tem várias pessoas que deram negativos em suas postagens, por isso deve não gostar disso, mas o meu conselho seria rever o que posta, porque acha que tem tantas pessoas negativando suas coisas por perseguição? Por acaso você pode ter ficado bravo com isso e achando que foi determinada pessoa pode ter negativado de volta na pessoa que acha que te negativou?

Comment: Geralmente meus upvotes são porque a resposta foi útil, ou um dia poderá a ser, pra mim.

Comment: @Mariero, quando a isso eu já fiz a devida reclamação e já obtive uma resposta via email sobre o ocorrido. Apesar de até hoje não ter entendido o motivo.

Comment: Como eu disse, eu não ligo tanto para os negativos nas minhas respostas (ou perguntas), ligo mais pela banalização do voto negativo.

Comment: Ou então deveria ser obrigado a pessoa justificar o seu voto. Assim, o voto serviria de feedback para a pessoa que o recebeu e ajudaria a mesma a melhorar e entender o motivo pelo qual está recebendo. Não serviria apenas como forma punitiva.

Comment: @ThiaguinhoEmbasamento isso que você colocou sobre a justificativa do downvote eu acho interessante e ajudaria a melhorar a formatação das perguntas. Mas também geraria descontentamento, tem pessoas que não aceitam a orientação e levam para o lado pessoal olha isso https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5675/um-usu%c3%a1rio-est%c3%a1-confundindo-a-minha-pergunta-sem-parar o usuário interpretou o esclarecimento sobre a questão como um ataque a integridade da pergunta.

Comment: @AugustoVasques ,acho que descontentamento sempre terá. Mas o importante é tentar reduzir isso ao mínimo. Ele teve diversos downvotes lá. Agora imagine se todos aqueles downvotes fossem feitos seguidos pelo menos de uma justificativa mínima. Ele talvez notaria que todas as pessoas estavam com o mesmo pensamento em relação a sua pergunta. O cara teve -15 votos em uma e -8 votos na outra. Só serve para enfurecer mais o cara, que não consegue entender em quais pontos sua pergunta foi ruim. A justificativa também poderia ser nos upvotes. Acho que é algo que custaria nada e melhoraria a plataforma.

Comment: Tá certo que aqui ninguém deve ser babá. Mas acho que falta um pouco de carinho e complacência, dos usuários mais experientes com os mais novos, em relação a abordagem e forma de se comunicar. Acho que na área de T.I, principalmente com programação, existe um pouco de arrogância e prepotência por parte dos profissionais. Não vejo isso com frequência em outras áreas. Quando aumentam para 10 pontos a pontuação das perguntas, vejo que os responsáveis pela plataforma estão tentando mostrar a real essência dela que é a de ajudar pessoas. Parece que algumas pessoas estão aqui com outros objetivos.

Comment: @ThiaguinhoEmbasamento Sobre "obrigar as pessoas a justificarem o voto", já existe um [FAQ](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/357437) explicando porque não é assim (mesmo que vc discorde, sugiro que leia para entender os motivos, não deixa de ser interessante). Claro que a empresa pode mudar de ideia sem avisar ninguém (como fez agora mudando o valor dos votos), mas por enquanto é assim, e pra mudar, alguém teria que rebater todos os argumentos do FAQ, o que vira e mexe alguém tenta (em todos os metas da rede) e nunca consegue...

Comment: @ThiaguinhoEmbasamento você deu *feedback* em todos os negativos que você deu?

Comment: Não, assim como também não dei nos positivos. Como também não me deram nem nos negativos e nem nos positivos. Mas se a plataforma disponibilizar uma ferramenta para tal função, eu passaria a fazer a partir da atual data.

Comment: @ThiaguinhoEmbasamento. Mas precisa de uma ferramenta específica para emitir uma opinião justificando o voto? Se você é simpático a associar um comentário justificando um voto, como eu sou, não é a ausência de uma ferramenta que força esse comportamento que vai o impedir de comentar junto a seus votos.

Comment: @ThiaguinhoEmbasamento Apenas complementando, tem 2 pontos do [FAQ](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/357437) que concordo: 1- votos **não** são punição e servem primariamente para classificar conteúdo (não é só para quem postou, mas para qualquer visitante futuro saber a qualidade daquilo). 2- nada impede que as pessoas escrevam qualquer texto sem sentido, ou só escrevam "está errado, -1" pra poder votar. Nos positivos então, é pior ainda, imagine todos tendo que escrever "que legal, +1!" (na maioria dos votos positivos não tem muito o que escrever além disso). Não, seria ruído demais...

Comment: @ThiaguinhoEmbasamento Se tem gente que usa o voto para punir e sacanear, **a culpa é dessas pessoas que usam errado**, não do sistema de votação em si. Concordo que o sistema não é perfeito, há muitas distorções (gente que vota positivo em código que nem compila ou pergunta fora de escopo, etc) mas eu acho que funciona muito melhor que outros sites (em fóruns, por exemplo, era - e ainda é - muito difícil ter um sistema de classificação tão bom quanto o do Stack Overflow). Bem ou mal, apesar da qualidade geral estar caindo, ainda é um dos melhores sites com conteúdo bom sobre programação.

Comment: Eu não dou muitos votos negativos. E nunca falei que eu era o bonzinho e legal daqui. Apenas sugeri uma ferramenta para a plataforma. Não sou tão tolo pra ser o único aqui a fazer isso. Gostaria que virasse uma prática geral.

Comment: @hkotsubo, acho a plataforma ótima. Apenas sugeri uma mudança que talvez gerasse melhorias para a comunidade.