# Quais foram as consequências de aumentar o valor do voto em perguntas para 10?

Tags: debate

Estamos a pouco de completar 2 meses desde que foi alterado o valor do voto em perguntas para 10.

- [Alteração na pontuação em perguntas: votos positivos passarão a valer 10 pontos ao invés de 5](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8038/5878)

Já temos como avaliar quais foram as consequências disso?

- Houve um aumento nos votos em perguntas?
- Houve um aumento na **qualidade** das perguntas dado o novo incentivo?
- Houve um aumento na **quantidade** das perguntas?

Em contrapartida, quais foram as consequências do ajuste de reputação de forma retroativa, em que vários usuários tiveram suas reputações corrigidas? Esses usuários fizeram uso das ferramentas que se tornaram disponíveis nessa transição? Se sim, as utilizaram corretamente ou impactaram negativamente no site? Se não, por que não?

Eu particularmente não vi mudanças significativas nesses dois meses e arrisco-me a afirmar que a pontuação dos votos em perguntas afetava minimamente o comportamento dos usuários.

Foi uma ação positiva, negativa ou foi em vão?

[How can we evaluate what were the impacts of "Rewarding the Question Askers" on a specific site?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/341856/369699)

Comment: Isso foi criado só para incentivar as pessoas perguntarem mesmo, não foi pra melhorar a qualidade. Só para dar pontos e a pessoa que fez uma pergunta qualquer ficar feliz em ter pontos, mesmo que seja uma só pessoa votando porque achou a pergunta curiosa, mesmo sendo ruim. Não trará nada positivo, inclusive porque não veio junto com outras medidas. Pra mim é ruim porque coloca peso na participação mesmo sem qualidade, mesmo que não envolva algum conhecimento.

Comment: Eu acho que deveria ter o peso das perguntas reduzido e o peso do negativo na pergunta aumentado para realmente criar problema para quem faz perguntas ruins, até porque as pessoas evitam negativar mesmo coisas claramente muito ruins. Eu acho triste que a SE praticamente não se comunica mais com a comunidade, e fica usando esses artifícios para impor sua vontade de transformar em um site de quantidade de dúvidas específicas mudando a visão original que era um repositório de conhecimento com qualidade. Só andamos pra trás e por isso praticamente não tem mais gente boa respondendo.

Comment: Eu nem acho que eles esperam muito que tenha aumento de perguntas no curto prazo. Especulando um pouco mais dá a impressão que eles querem com isso matar as últimas forças de quem preza a qualidade a deixar tudo como o YR!. Isto acontecendo haverá aumento de perguntas e de audiência, aumentando o valor da empresa. Agora podemos especular mais já que eles resolveram que a comunidade não tema mais importância mesmo. E justamente por causa disto eu começo me preocupar menos com a opinião deles.

Comment: Eu estou quase montando uma pergunta no Meta no formato lista de "perguntas que a SE ainda não respondeu" xD

Comment: Aliás, poderia existir uma tag para isso (para sinalizar que uma pergunta demanda a participação deles - e que não é apenas uma discussão interna).

Comment: tem, mas não ligam mais :) Vide o monte de coisa que tem `bug` e tem que falar pra eles quais os *bugs* que queremos tratados. Eu já ando a começar pensar o contrário, melhor sem eles :D mesmo no metão não dão uma dentro, eles perderam a mão da comunidade de vez e só as pessoas que fizeram isto podem reconhecer que isto é um problema e começar mudar, provavelmente trocando todo mundo, porque a mudança pra pior começou com uma mudança de pessoas.

Comment: Em termos de gamificação, mudança retroativa é sempre traição.

Comment: Aumento de trafego no site, agora já vale a pena fazer perguntas péssimas, se chover um like já tem 10 pontinhos.

Comment: @Maniero aliás, eu acho interessante as pessoas que tem chuvas e chuvas de negativos (fazia tempo que eu não via a comunidade tão unida para negativar posts deixando claro que algo está errado) continuarem representando a empresa, enquanto com moderador expulso arbitrariamente precisa-se "negociar longe dos olhos da comunidade".

Comment: Um exemplo do que poderia ter sido feito para mostrar que realmente querem recompensar quem faz pergunta de qualidade e não apenas dar pontos para alegrar quem faz **qualquer** pergunta: os pontos só são computados quando a pergunta atinge 3 votos positivos e que os negativos sejam inferiores a 20% dos positivos. Então se for dado um negativo só ganha pontos se tiver 6 positivos (total 58 pontos), ou precisa 11 pra ganhar pontos se tiver 2 negativos. Ou então para cada negativo pelo menos outros 3 positivos para ir amortizando um pouco, enfim, é só questão de ajustar.

Comment: Um fator negativo que percebi nisso é que o usuário novo consegue mais facilmente o privilégio de votar alcançando os 15pts mais rapidamente. Bastam 2 votos positivos numa pergunta já faz 20pts. Aliás, na minha opinião, esses 15pts deveriam ter subido também para, digamos, uns 50pts ou 100pts, ou pelo menos proporcionalmente.